# D3 bar chart left aligned x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

How do I retain the x-axis as 100% of the container width while maintaining left aligned ticks with some padding.

```
  this.xAxis = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, this.barWidth * this.data.length], 1);
```

If I change the `range` to `.range([0, this.svgWidth])`, the width is correct but my ticks are evenly spread out which is not my desired outcome.

Comment: Can you give more details with code in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third arguments are not accepted anymore in `range` when you use a band scale. Instead, you'll have to use `paddingInner` and `paddingOuter`.

So, change your snippet to this:

```
this.xAxis = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, this.svgWidth])
    .paddingInner(someValue)
    .paddingOuter(someValue);
```

Tweak with `someValue` until you find the desired outcome.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track but I still cant figure out how to make the space between each tick smaller. This is how it looks http://imgur.com/86037Wh.

Comment: D3 will spread the ticks according to your range. In that case, maybe the solution is simply narrowing the range.

Comment: If I narrow the range, i lose the 100% width of the x-axis. Is there a way to retain the x-axis to be 100% of the containers width?

Comment: You want to keep 100% of the width, but you want to move the ticks to the left and leave a big gap to the right, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah thats my desired outcome

Comment: There is only one solution, then: create empty values in the domain and then remove the corresponding ticks. But your whole chart will be empty at the right... that's make no sense to me.

Comment: Yeah it makes no sense to me as well but I'm following a design from a designer :(